# Extracting data from VBScript using regex

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-ise

I'm entirely new to scripting, and I'm trying to run a script to extract data from a .vbs file using windows powershell; the file looks something like this:

```
...
data = field1
...
data = field2
...
data = field3
...
data = field4
...
```

So far I have:

```
$input_path = 'C:\folder\file.vbs'
$output_file = 'C:\folder\extracted_data.txt'
$regex = 'data = [A-Za-z0-9]*'
select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches} | % {$_.Value} > $output_file
```

When I run the script, the `extracted_data.txt` file is completely empty. But if I copy all the text in the .vsb file into a new `file.txt` file, and change the input path to read from that file instead, the data is extracted as it should be; `extracted_data.txt` looks something like this:

```
data = field1
data = field2
data = field3
data = field4
...
```

How can I modify my script then to make sure it reads from the text in the .vsb file?

**EDIT:**

Checked the permissions on the file:

```
PS C:\Users\largox> Get-Acl C:\Lara\IISData-LIVE.vbs | Format-List


Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\folder\file.vbs'
Owner  : BUILTIN\Administrators
Group  : COMP1\Domain Users
Access : BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
         BUILTIN\Users Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
         NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users Allow  Modify, Synchronize
```

So it doesn't appear to be a read/write permission issue, unless the last line indicates something of which I'm unaware?

Comment: I don't think you've put enough information to answer. If your code works against one file and fails against another identical file, then it's not your code, it's permissions or a typo in the path, or similar. If the other file is not identical, then it's something you're doing during the copy paste - e.g. saving in a different encoding. Change your `>` to `>>` so it will append instead of overwriting and see if it outputs anything at all.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, the files aren't identical. My script is able to read from a .txt file, but not from a .vbs file. Checked the encoding as well, it's the same (UTF-8 without BOM). However, they both contain the same text. Is there something about the vbs file that makes its source code unreadable from a powershell script?

Comment: No, it's just a text file named `.vbs`. They aren't compiled, or encrypted or digitally locked or protected by Windows or anything. In PowerShell ISE run `get-content 'c:\folder\file.vbs'`, what does it do? Is your PowerShell running in a scheduled task? Is there a network drive involved? Is the file or folder named starting with a t and your code is actually inserting `\t` a tab character in the name by mistake?

Comment: Examples of failed/incomplete output and the corresponding input might be helpful.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, made an edit to include that information

Comment: Have a look at your **regex** expression. It only matches "data", "space", "=", "space" and "**one** alphanumeric character", You can't get the expected output using this. Also, could there be a TAB instead of space on you .vbs file?

Comment: @JanChrbolka, you're right, and I've fixed the bug, but that's not really the point of my questions regardless.

Comment: Could it be something really trivial? The variable with your output path is named `$output_path`, but you're redirecting the output to `$output_file` (which is not initialized, so you're effectively redirecting to `$null`).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers nope, that's just another bug (wrote the code from scratch rather than copy/paste-ing) - fixed that one as well. I'm guessing it has something to do with a difference between the files, but I'm having trouble figuring it out.

Comment: as @TessellatingHeckler stated, and I don't think your understanding, the problem is not a difference in the files (not at least encoding/encryption/compliled differences) - **.vbs** = regular vbs (can be read same as a text file); if it was encoded differently it would be a **.vbe** file

Comment: Resuggesting *In PowerShell ISE run get-content 'c:\folder\file.vbs', what does it do?*. Do you have any antivirus running? They often hate useful things like vbscript files.